# Atom Javascript Console

Tags: console

I've tried to use Script and atom-js-console on atom but when I run code using script I get this message 'env: node: No such file or directory'. How can I get a console that works with running javascript code on atom.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you hook it up to a web but if you want it inside of the atom-editor itself then there are packages for running it inside of the atom editor it self. Note: These packages copy chromes"inspect" view so don't expect it to be very optimised.

Comment: Do you know of any atom Javascript consoles that work on atom?

Comment: Yes, Just search JavaScript Console in the Installer Package and there are tons of options.